# Creating json object without keys from array in android

Tags: android, arraylist, json

Is there any way to create json object with only values and no keys, from array list in android?
 I have array list like this

```
[12,name,description]
```

But i need to convert this to JSON Object like this

```
{"12","name","description"}
```

How to do this? Can anyone help?

Comment: What is use of this kind of `JsonObject`? How will you fetch value after creating object?

Comment: I need to send this json object through volley post method to server side where it will be fetched using jersey.

Comment: you better create a String manually.. **That will not be called a `JsonObject`** .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot create `JSONObject` without its key.

> A modifiable set of name/value mappings. Names are unique, non-null
>   strings.

[Source](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)

Definition itself says `names are unique, non-null`so you need to use key-value pair only, however it it possible to create `JSONArray` like this, but in that case also that `JSONArray` have some key.

```
"someKey":["a","b","c"]
```

So in this case also `JSONArray` needs to define under some key.